# Chakra extendTheme increases the first load size of NextJS App

Tags: optimization, next.js, chakra-ui

I have a NextJS App, where I am using Chakra UI. I observed that when I use the `ChakraProvider` without a custom theme, the first load stats given by `@next/bundle-analyzer` are decent, in the green zone. But when I add custom theme, it rises up quite a bit into the yellow zone, and VS Code's Import Cost Extension gives me a hint that it might be because of the `extendTheme` function of Chakra.

Is there any way to tackle this issue?

My `src/design/theme.ts` file:

```js
import { type ThemeConfig } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { mode, Styles } from "@chakra-ui/theme-tools";
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/theme-utils";
import { Be_Vietnam_Pro, PT_Serif, Inter } from "next/font/google";

const config: ThemeConfig = {
  initialColorMode: "light",
  useSystemColorMode: false,
};

const styles: Styles = {
  global: (props) => ({
    body: {
      bgImage: "url(/backgrounds/dark-bg.svg)",
      bgAttachment: "fixed",
      bgRepeat: "no-repeat",
      bgSize: "cover",
      fontFamily: mode(inter.style.fontFamily, inter.style.fontFamily)(props),
      userSelect: "none",
      scrollbarGutter: "stable both-edges",
    },
    "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
      width: "14px",
    },
    "&::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
      border: "4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
      backgroundClip: "padding-box",
      borderRadius: "9999px",
      backgroundColor: "#AAAAAA",
    },
  }),
};

const beVietnamPro = Be_Vietnam_Pro({
  weight: ["100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

const inter = Inter({
  weight: ["100", "200", "300", "400", "500", "600", "700", "800", "900"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

const ptSerif = PT_Serif({
  weight: ["400", "700"],
  subsets: ["latin"],
});

const theme = extendTheme({
  config,
  fonts: {
    beVietnamPro: beVietnamPro.style.fontFamily,
    inter: inter.style.fontFamily,
    ptSerif: ptSerif.style.fontFamily,
  },
  styles,
});

export default theme;
```

In the above, this is what Import Cost shows me:
[image]

Case 1:
`src/pages/_app.tsx`

```js
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

// import theme from "@design/theme";

const ChakraProvider = dynamic(() =>
  import("@chakra-ui/provider").then((mod) => mod.ChakraProvider)
);

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

With the above, this is the result of bundle analysis:
[image]

Case 2:
`src/pages/_app.tsx`

```js
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

import theme from "@design/theme";

const ChakraProvider = dynamic(() =>
  import("@chakra-ui/provider").then((mod) => mod.ChakraProvider)
);

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

With the above, this is the result of bundle analysis:
[image]

Comment: From personal experience, Chakra UI; While definitely an extensive component library, is way to heavy to be used for larger production applications. I'd recommend you switch to something like Tailwind CSS.